# Gmail using pub/sub push URL

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I have used OAuth 2.0 client ID approach to fetch messages from gmail inbox and do the processing further in our java application. This functionality is working as expected, with a scheduler which checks periodically for UNREAD emails in INBOX.

However, we want to use the google pub/sub API to PUSH the message to a endpoint URL in our application. I have followed the steps mentioned in https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push documentation. I have done the setup required for receiving any published message on the created topic. If I manually post a message from google console to the topic I an receiving the notification on my application endpoint.

The issue I am facing is related to the watch request part. The google API explorer doesnt work for watch request and give the following error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidArgument",
    "message": "Invalid topicName does not match projects/google.com:apisexplorerconsole/topics/*"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid topicName does not match projects/google.com:apisexplorerconsole/topics/*"
 }
}
```

I want to know if somehow manually from the google UI or through java code using OAuth Client ID approach, can I trigger the watch request?

Comment: I don't think that's one of the commands that's going t work using the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DalmTo. Is there anyway I can invoke the watch request using java api via OAuth client ID approach?

Comment: I don't see why not the client library supports it. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch This one gives the error mentioned above. Also I couldnt find any pointers in java api-client-library for achieving this.

Comment: I think you should edit your question and show your code.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  there is sample code for java on the page I linked